# How to pass event into javascript function with React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
  const [loc, setLoc] = useState(default);
 
  const handleChanges = (event, data, setLocFunction) => {
        const storedLoc = [...data];

        storedLoc[event.target.dataset.id][event.target.name] = event.target.value;

        setLocFunction(storedLoc);
    };
```

That's my setup then in my JSX I am trying to pass those value to my handleChange function like so:

```
                                <input
                                className="ddRowLat"
                                type="text"
                                onChange={handleLocChanges(event, loc, setLoc}
                                key={index}
                                value={item.lat}
                                data-id={index}
                                name="lat"
                               />
```

but I'm encountering an eslint rule https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-globals for the event. What's the correct solution to this issue?

Comment: I think it's just the "event" variable name. Try to change to "e" or something like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest change you can make from what you have currently would be this:

```
onChange={event => handleLocChanges(event, loc, setLoc)}
```

Comment: That was the simplest change out of all three recommendations. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make `handleChanges` a HOF which, when called, returns a function that takes `event` as the first parameter:

```
const handleChanges = (data, setLocFunction) => event => {
```

```
onChange={handleLocChanges(loc, setLoc)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the parameter name:

```
const handleChanges = (e, data, setLocFunction) => {
    const storedLoc = [...data];

    storedLoc[event.target.dataset.id][e.target.name] = e.target.value;

    setLocFunction(storedLoc);
};
```